# Android Camera2 Flash and manual control

Tags: android, android-camera, camera2

I tried to build a Camera2 Application for Manual Capture Control. The manual settings do not work, when Flash is enabled (TORCH).

I tested it on the [Google Camera2Basic Sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic) and added these lines:

```
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_OFF);

                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_MODE_OFF);
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.SENSOR_SENSITIVITY, 4000);
                            mPreviewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                                    CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

The problem is, that the Sensitivity is 4000 for just the very first frame (or so it seems). Then it gets set to 100, which I guess is the default.

Btw. I'm using a Nexus 6 to test.

So my question is, is there a way to have manual control and flash on at the same time?